# creating an upwards series in c++

Tags: c++, sum

[Screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLUHu.jpg)

Hey, I have just started learning C++ and I am trying to get it to sum the series:

> K+N−1∑n=K  [-1^(n)/(n+1)2]

I have managed to get it to tell me the nth term previously, but now I would like to for each term in the series, starting with the kth and going in sequence to the last (k+n-1st), add this term to the running sum.
I need to use a function `direct_up()` which uses the function `term()`. I defined initially and test it in the main.

I know I am missing something and am a bit confused about how to use the functions and that I may have made a few mistakes. So I would be very grateful for some advice or help. I have attached a picture of what I have done so far, as well as typed it below.

```
using namespace std;

double term(int n) { 
    double y;
    if(n%2==1) {
        y = -1.0/((n+1.0)*(n+1.0));
    } else {
        y = 1.0/((n+1.0)*(n+1.0));
    }
    return y;
}

double direct_up(int k, int n) {
    int startingnumber = k;
    for (int i = startingnumber; i <= k+n; i++) {
        cout << n << term(n) << endl;
    }
    return n;
}

int main() {
    double n;
    int k;
    cout.precision(16);
    cout << "enter number of terms";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "enter a value for k";
    cin >> k;
    cout << "here is the value" << direct_up(k,n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tour function `term()` could look somewhat nicer; e.g., by using `#include<cmath>` you could write  `double y = std::pow(-1,n)/std::pow(n+1,2);`

Comment: yeah i was just told to use iostream to keep it simple for now but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want to do:

```
double direct_up(int k, int n) 
{
    int startingnumber = k;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = startingnumber; i <= k+n; i++) {
        sum += term(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Here's how to do it without keeping your own running sum as you asked in your comment:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

double direct_up(int k, int n) 
{
    int startingnumber = k;
    std::vector<double> terms;
    for (int i = startingnumber; i <= k+n; i++) {
        terms.push_back(term(i));
    }
    return accumulate(terms.begin(), terms.end(), 0.0);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I added what you gave and it compiled, but my program returns 0 as the answer no matter what values I put in, would you have any idea why?

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!! I was wondering, is there a way of doing it without using 'sum'? or is that the only way?

Comment: Yes, you can use `std::accumulate` if you don't want to keep your own running sum. I've added that to my answer.